questions on stochastic kernels and pushforward operator
Let $f:X \rightarrow \Delta (Y)$ and $g:X \rightarrow \Delta (X)$ be two kernels. For any bounded measurable function $h_Y:Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$ define $F(h_Y):X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(h_Y)(x)=\int_{Y} h_Y(y) f(x)(dy) $. Let $\mathbb{F}=\{F(h_Y)| h_Y:Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}$. Similarly, define $G(h_X)$ such that $G(h_X)(x)=\int_{X} h_X(x') g(x)(dx') $ and $\mathbb{G}=\{G(h_X)| h_X:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}$. Is the following generally true? Given any $f$, there exists $g$ such that $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{G}$? This will be true if $X$ and $Y$ are finite, or uncountable Polish spaces.
